# Can I upload an app to the App Store using a MacOS VM on my Windows without any legal troubles?

Tags: ios, windows, macos, app-store, virtual-machine

Basically, I don't have a Mac.

But I'm aware of being able to virtually run a Mac throw solutions like Virtual Box or VMware on my Windows, despite how slow it will be. (I know it technically isn't legal).

What I'm asking is, will I be able to actually upload the compiled app to the app store without issues? Such as the App Store recognizing that it is not a legitimate device or something?

Comment: I remember one WWDC where Steve Jobs announced a new feature "activation keys"; it was just a joke having a dig at Microsoft Windows. You are violating the license agreement by running macOS on non-Apple hardware, but Apple doesn't perform any checks. You can build and upload iOS apps using cloud solutions like Microsoft Azure DevOps and that is definitely running in a virtual container.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a legal question

Comment: @Paulw11 so basically, Apple wouldn't be able to know, and nothing bad will happen to me?